# Azure B2C Custom Extension Attribute Not Updating

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to add/update a value to a custom extension attribute for a user in Azure AD B2C.  The attribute is an AccountNumber with the type as string.  I have two different Azure environments I'm working out of.  One is for my local/staging environments, and the other is client's production Azure environment.  My local and staging are working fine, but I cannot seem to get this attribute to get updated through the production instance, which is leading me to think I'm missing some sort of permission/configuration within the Azure instance itself rather than code, but let's see.

Here are the steps I've taken in Azure:

1. Within the B2C I've setup my application.  For the API Access section I have 2 selections

   - Acquire an id_token for users (openid)
   - Acquire a refresh_token for users (offline_access)
2. I have two user flows both of which are returning AccountNumber as a claim.
3. Within App registrations (NOT legacy), I've added my application as well.  It does have a warning about not being supported yet in B2C, but I have this in my staging instance as well.  I have the following for API Permissions that have been selected for this application.  I've gone back and forth adding the offline_access, openid, and profile. (All are uder Microsoft Graph Delegated)

   - User.Read
   - User.ReadWrite
   - offline_access
   - openid
   - profile
4. In App registrations/Authentication tab I've enabled implicit grant flow and checked both Access tokens and ID tokens
5. Ive taken the b2c-extensions-app app ID and saved it within my code for using to update the extensions attribute (dashes removed)

Web.config

```
<add key="ida:NonAdminScopes" value="User.Read User.ReadWrite" />
<add key="ida:AdminScopes" value="Directory.AccessAsUser.All User.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All" />
```

Here is where I'm building and making the request. Yes, I realize I'm doing this a more manual way, but I'm also working with Sitecore which has required me to keep some older dlls and this is where I've landed after days of frustration.

```
private async Task<string> SendGraphPatchRequest(string json, string objectId)
        {
            var graphEndpoint = new Uri(string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{0}/users/{1}", Tenant, objectId));
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = graphEndpoint })
            {
                using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), graphEndpoint))
                {
                    var token = await GetOrCreateAccessToken();

                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                    {
                        requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    }

                    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Logger.Error(string.Format("Error -> RequestMessage: {0}", error));

                        object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
                        throw new WebException("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
                    }
                }
            }

            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

The line that is creating the access token does use ClientCredentials

```
_accessToken = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", _credentials);
```

An example of the request body content

```
{"extension_[extensionAppId]_AccountNumber":"123456"}
```

And when I try to make this request with Postman (I had a line of code where I was logging the token that gets created from the above code snippet - not sure if that will actually work or not), here is the response I get back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "####",
      "date": "2019-08-21T15:06:45"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct b2c-extensions-app ID in your production environment? This is a shot in the dark, but you could also try step 1.4 from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect permissions on the App Reg for MS Graph API.
Probably you have consented to other permissions in your dev tenants then deselected them later, it doesn’t remove consent.

Add read/write directory under Application permissions since you use client credentials in code,delegated permissions won’t do anything here. Also click Grant Permissions once you save the new permissions.